# fetch returns only one row when i get it from cache

Tags: php, mysql, caching, pdo, phpfastcache

I'm trying to adopt a cache class to use on my web page.

Simple logic is like that:

Try to get data from cache:

- If there is not: run query and set this as a cache.
- If there is: show data from cache.

**my code**

```
<?php
// Require Library
require_once("phpfastcache.php");
$cache = phpFastCache();

//lets get it from cache.
$r = $cache->get("cachethis");

if($r == null) {

    echo " THIS TIME RUN WITHOUT CACHE <br> ";
    $time_start = microtime(true);

    $query = $handler->query("SELECT * FROM members");
        while($r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        //echo
        echo "$r[id]";

        //lets cache query above.
        $cache->set("cachethis", $r, 10);

        }

    $time_end = microtime(true);
    $time = ($time_end - $time_start);
    echo "<p>done in " . $time . " seconds</p>";

} 
//if ($r != null)
else {
    echo "RUN WITH CACHE. YES.<br>  ";
    $time_start = microtime(true);

    //echo from cache..
    echo "$r[id]";
    $time_end = microtime(true);
    $time = ($time_end - $time_start);
    echo "<p>cache done in " . $time . " seconds</p>";
}

?>
```

**my output and problem**

I have two rows.

When I fetch them from query, my code outputs both of them. Which is nice.

```
row1
row2
```

But when page brings it to me from cache, it outputs only last row.

```
row2
```

**what i tried**

I tried to use `fetchAll()` function instead of `fetch()` but this time I'm getting Notice: Undefined index: id error.

So I'm stuck and need your help.

Comment: do you want to have cache for every record or cache for all records?

Comment: Update your question with the `get` and `set` method of `Cache` class?

Comment: @MaxP. I want to cache all records at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if for all records at once, use `fetchAll`

```
$r = $cache->get("cachethis");

if(!is_array($r)) {
    // not in cache, from db
    $query = $handler->query("SELECT * FROM members");
    $r = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $cache->set("cachethis", $r, 10);
}

foreach($r as $v) echo $v['id']."<br>";
```